# installing react-navigation with npm gives an error

Tags: react-native, npm, react-native-navigation

I am aware that there are already questions about this but they didn't work and most of them are for create-react-native-app but I am using expo.

I run `npm install react-navigation` and it gives me this error:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: file-uri-to-path@1.0.0 (node_modules\file-uri-to-path):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\yaelp\Downloads\meals-cat\node_modules\file-uri-to-path' -> 'C:\Users\yaelp\Downloads\meals-cat\node_modules\.file-uri-to-path.DELETE'

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\yaelp\Downloads\meals-cat\node_modules\hoist-non-react-statics
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\yaelp\Downloads\meals-cat\node_modules\.hoist-non-react-statics.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\yaelp\Downloads\meals-cat\node_modules\hoist-non-react-statics' -> 'C:\Users\yaelp\Downloads\meals-cat\node_modules\.hoist-non-react-statics.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\yaelp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-01T17_02_25_868Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to install all dependencies (from the documentation of react-navigation).

Run:

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you resolved your issue by now (more than a month has passed since you posted the question). For those who might get it (like I did), here are some possible solutions:

1. Install react-navigation with yarn:
   In the official [react-navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/) there is a yarn install command:

   yarn add react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
2. Try deleting package-lock.json file and then try installing react-navigation with npm again
3. Killing your app and then trying to install react-navigation,
4. Deleting your node_modules and do `npm i` again,
5. Try uninstalling node, npm and everything with it (and reinstalled everything afterwards of course).

I got these solutions from this [github issue](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/900). I hope one of them will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `expo install react-navigation` as you are using expo.

If you need to use npm, try:

`npm install react-navigation --force`

Answer (score 0):

Try to run npm install,  then **npm install @react-navigation/native** from [reactnavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/)